# How to add logout button IN SSRS web page?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, reporting, database-user, kill

I have such question. Is it possible to add logout functionality for current user IN SSRS web page in browser?

Comment: What does that mean?...what would you expect the Logout button to do?...take you to a different website?

Comment: I expect when user click on button logout,  he will be logouted from ssrs webpage,and ssrs web page will ask the user to enter username and password. Just like in facebook, when man login to his account from his girlfriend computer, he entered his loginname and password. When he finish his conversation, he logout from the account.

Comment: That's not how SSRS was designed. It automatically tries to authenticate as the logged in user of the computer. Depending on your network settings, and how you configure the SSRS server, it may need to have the browser prompt you for your credentials one time. But then you remain authenticated for the rest of the session. Without re-writing SSRS with some crazy template, the only way to log out is to end the session by closing the browser. What is your end goal for wanting this?